# Muting new members upon joining a server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My idea is pretty simple and I hope someone could lead me to a good solution. so in the event `GuildMemberAdd`, I'm trying to make it mute anyone who joined the server, so if I'm new to the server I'll get muted until someone from the staff unmute me which should be a good thing for spammers and so on. I tried to do it myself by defining a `mute` role

```js
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
if(!member.user.bot) member.addRole(muterole);
```

but it always kept on saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined.` whenever I'm trying to join with a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is `undefined`, which would make sense because the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event takes a listener taking only one parameter: the guild member.

Use this for Discord.js v11 (which is what you seem to be using):

```js
// I used const instead of let because it's very unlikely you would change muteRole.
// const makes it an immutable variable.

// Note I used member.guild here not message.guild
const muteRole = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Muted')
if (!member.user.bot) member.addRole(muteRole)
```

For v12/13 (the latest version):

```js
const muteRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted')
if (!member.user.bot) member.roles.add(muteRole)
```

Comment: how did i not think about member, omg i feel dumb. thank you so much for your help, and yes i use v11.